# How to write a MongoDB query to perform the following update?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

I want to update the inner fields of specific questions for a specific exam such as user_answer, isAnswered, etc in the Mongo document below.

[image]

Document File for the above image :

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"60508fb1c4b07a4134e75644"},
  "student_id":"5faaac5d35b7ba4ed406e765",
  "exams":[
    {"score":null,
     "time_taken":null,
     "exam_taken":true,
     "_id":{"$oid":"60508fb1c4b07a4134e75645"},
     "exam_id":"5fbfc8ea9831540072063e62",
     "questions":[
       {"user_answer":null,
        "isAnswered":false,
        "isUnanswered":true,
        "isFlagged":false,
        "_id":{"$oid":"5fbfc8659831540072063e61"}
       }
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote a query for the same but it doesn't work.

```
try{
   await req.db
    .collection('result')
    .findOneAndUpdate({ student_id: ObjectId("5faaac5d35b7ba4ed406e765"), "exams._id": ObjectId(exam_id),"exams.questions._id":ObjectId(question_id) }, {
      $set: {
        'questions.$.user_answer': answer,
        'questions.$.isAnswered':true,
        'questions.$.isUnanswered':false,
        'questions.$.isFlagged':false
      }
    }
    );
  res.status(201).end();
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Though I am sure there is something wrong with the query itself, I'll highly appreciate it if anyone of you people can tell me how to perform such type of update.

*Thank you for the same*

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Thank you for informing me, I've included the part of the image which can be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MongoDB 3.5.12, you can use the update operator with the option [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-array-filters) to updated nested array elements.

```
   db.collection.update({
  "student_id": ObjectId("5faaac5d35b7ba4ed406e765"),
  "exams.exam_id": ObjectId("5fbfc8ea9831540072063e62")
},
{
  $set: {
    "exams.$.questions.$[question].user_answer": "You are the best",
    "exams.$.questions.$[question].isAnswered": true,
    "exams.$.questions.$[question].isUnanswered": false,
    "exams.$.questions.$[question].isFlagged": false
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "question._id": ObjectId("5fbfc8659831540072063e61")
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for this approach. But in my query, I also have to check for the particular exam using `exam_id` from the exam array how can I achieve that using this query?

Comment: I just modified my answer, check it out, I hope it help.